# Question about flatness

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Proposition 2.9. on page 304 of Silverman's textbook Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves:

> Let $R$ be a DVR with field of fractions $K$, residue field $k$, and maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $X$ be an integral (i.e., reduced and irreducible) $R$-scheme of finite type over $R$ whose generic fiber $X_{\eta}/K$ is non-empty. Then $X$ is a smooth $R$-scheme if and only if $X_{\eta}(\overline{K})$ and $X_{\mathfrak{p}}(\overline{k})$ contain no singular points.

In the begining of its proof, Silverman claims

> The scheme $X$ is irreducible, so it has a unique generic point. Our assumption that the generic fiber $X_{\eta}$ is nonempty shows that the generic point of $X$ maps to the generic point of $\text{Spec}\; R$, so $X$ is flat over $\text{Spec}\; R$ from Hartshorne [1, III.9.7].

My question is that, why the generic fiber $X_{\eta}$ being nonempty shows that the generic point of $X$ maps to the generic point of $\text{Spec}\; R$? Moreover, how does the flatness criterion (III.9.7.) in Hartshorne implies that $X$ is flat over $\text{Spec}\; R$? Proposition III.9.7. in Hartshorne stats that

> Given a morphism of schemes $f: X \rightarrow Y$ with $Y$ integral and regular of dimension $1$. Then $f$ is flat if and only if every associated point $x \in X$ maps to the generic point of $Y$.

In our case, we have $Y = \text{Spec}\; R$ which has two points $0$ and $\mathfrak{p}$. But then what even are the associated points of $X$? By reading Silverman's claim, it seems like the generic point of $X$ should be the only associated point of $X$?

Also in Remark 7.7 on page 345:

> Let $R$ be a DVR and $C \subset \mathbb{A}_R^2$ an arithmetic surfaced defined by a single equation $$f(x,y) = 0\;\;\;\;\;\text{for some polynomial $f \in R[x,y].$}$$
> i.e., $C = \text{Spec}\; R[x,y]/(f)$. In order to ensure that $C$ is a two dimensional scheme whose special fiber has dimension one, we will assume
> that $f$ is not a constant polynomial and that at least one coefficient of $f$ is a unit in $R$. In fancier terminology, this means that $C$ is flat over $R$.

I'd like to ask how does the condition Silverman imposes imply that $C$ is flat over $R$?

Comment: This is a little jumbled right now and requires your potential answerers to open two different books! Please make an [edit] to straighten things out and to put the full statements you're concerned about in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I have now edited my question so that it is more readable.

Comment: $X$ is integral, so its only associated point is the generic point! Another way to put it is that a module over a Dedekind domain is flat iff it is torsion-free. Because $X$ is integral, it is torsion free iff its function field contains $R$, iff the generic fiber is nonempty.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if the only associated point of $X$ is the generic point, do we automatically get that the generic point is sent to the generic point of $\text{Spec}\; R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim**. If $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of irreducible schemes with generic points $\eta_X$ and $\eta_Y$ respectively, then either $f(\eta_X)=\eta_Y$ or $f(X)$ is contained in a proper closed subset of $Y$.

*Proof.* If $f(\eta_X)=\eta_Y$, then $\overline{f(X)} \supset \overline{\{f(\eta_X)\}} \supset \overline{\{\eta_Y\}} = Y$. On the other hand, $f(X)=f(\overline{\{\eta_X\}})\subset \overline{f(\eta_X)}$, so if $f(\eta_X)\neq \eta_Y$ then $f(X)$ is contained in the closed subset $\overline{f(\eta_X)}$, which is proper because $\eta_Y$ is the only point with closure $Y$. $\blacksquare$

This deals with the first question: if the image of the generic point of $X$ is not the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$, then $f(X)$ would be contained in a closed subset and the fiber over the generic point would be empty.

The flatness criterion has already been mentioned in the comment. The key idea is that the only associated point on a noetherian integral scheme is the generic point. Here's how to see this: for a noetherian scheme, the definition of an associated point is one where the maximal ideal of the local ring consists entirely of zero-divisors. For an integral scheme, this condition is only satisfied at the generic point, so the unique associated point of $X$ is $\eta_X$ which maps to the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ and therefore we may apply the criteria for flatness from Hartshorne.

The final claim follows from the above observation with a little bit more work. If all the coefficients of $f$ are in the maximal ideal, then there is an irreducible component of $V(f)\subset\Bbb A^2_R$ which maps only to the special point: if $r$ is a uniformizer for $R$, then the statement that all coefficients of $f$ are in the maximal ideal implies that $f=r^ng$ for $n>0$ and some $g\in R[x,y]$ which has a coefficient which is a unit. Then $V(f)=V(r^n)\cup V(g)$, and the generic point of $V(r^n)$, which is an associated point of $V(f)$, does not map to the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$. Thus $V(f)\to\operatorname{Spec} R$ cannot be flat if $r\mid f$, and in fact one can show by running this argument backwards that this is an equivalence.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: Sorry it has been a while since your answer was posted, but can you elaborate a bit more on what the generic point of $V(r^n)$ should be? Is it the zero ideal of $(R/(r^n))[x,y]$? If it is or it's something else, how do we then check that it is an associated point of $V(f)$?

Comment: The zero ideal of $(R/(r^n))[x,y]$ is not prime, so it can't be that, but you're on the right track - this space is an irreducible affine scheme, so the generic point is the unique minimal prime, which in this case is $\sqrt{(0)}=(r)$. To check that this is an associated point, we may compute that the local ring at this point is $(R/(r^n))[x,y]_{(r)}$ and every element of the maximal ideal of this ring, $(r)$, is nilpotent hence a zero divisor. Thus it is an associated point.

Comment: To check associated, are we computing $(R[x,y]/(f))_{(r)}$ or $(R/(r^n))[x,y]_{(r)}$? Either way I believe I have this direction. For the other direction would it be easier to assume $V(f) \rightarrow \text{Spec} \; R$ is not flat? Say, $a \in V(f)$ is an associated point that maps to $(r) \in \text{Spec} \; R$, i.e. $(r) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}_a \subset R[x,y]/(f)$. Since $a$ is associated, the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}_a \subset (R[x,y]/(f))_{\mathfrak{p}_a}$ should consists only of zero divisors? I think I can then write $r\cdot h = f\cdot g$? But not sure how to continue from here...

Comment: First question: they're the same, the fact that $g$ has a coefficient not divisible by $r$ means that it's inverted when localizing at $(r)$ since it's not in the ideal $(r)$. I was perhaps a little quick there, though. Next question: sure, you can work that way, and you're off to a solid start. Knowing that the associated point maps to the special point then gives you that $R\subset (R[x,y]/f)_p$ is a local map of local rings, then assuming $f$ of positive degree shows that $r$ is nonzero in the image, so $r$ is a zero divisor, or $r$ divides $f$.

Comment: Doesn't $r$ being a zero divisor means $r \cdot h = f \cdot g$ for some polynomials $h,g \in (R[x,y]/(f))_p$? (since any multiple of $f$ is $0$ inside the quotient $R[x,y]/(f)$.) Do we know for sure that $r$ goes into $f$ but not $g$? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Actually, I'm liking this idea less now. The following feels much more direct to me: since $R$ is a DVR, it is a UFD, and therefore $R[x,y]$ is a UFD too. Factor $f=\prod p_i^{e_i}$ in to powers of irreducibles, so that the prime ideals over $f$ are $(p_i)$. These are the generic points of irreducible components of $V(f)$, and the statement that one maps to $(r)\subset R$ is exactly the statement that some $p_i=(r)$, or that $f$ is divisible by $r$. (Sorry for the messy comments, I've been a little distracted lately.)

Comment: Your comments are perfectly fine. All the help you provided are greatly appreciated. So I suppose both directions then boil down to the statements: The associated points of $V(f)$ are precisely the generic points of its irreducible components. And they look like $(p_i)$ for some irreducible $p_i$. Now such a $(p_i)$ mapping to the special point $(r) \in \text{Spec} \; R$ is then exactly the same as saying $p_i = r$ I assume?

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "I'd like to ask how does the condition Silverman imposes imply that C is flat over R?"

**Answer:** If $f(x,y):=\sum a_{i,j}x^iy^j \in R[x,y]$ it follows (Milne "Etale Cohomology", rmk. 2.6) $u:R\rightarrow R[x,y]/(f)$ is flat iff the ideal $I:=(a_{i,j})=(1)$ is trivial. Hence if one of the coefficients $a_{i,j}$ is a unit it follows $u$ is flat.

Comment: Thanks for this!